# mvc core передать в представление модель

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть форма в представлении передает данные в контроллер где записываются в БД. Нужно вернуть в представление Id вставленного обьекта. 
Делаю так `return View("Index", model);`
Данные Id не меняются. Как передать измененую модель в представление? 
Сделал через `return Redirect("Index");`, но смотрится это как коряво :(

Comment: Напишите код как экшена, который сохраняет в бд и возвращает представление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто,  `ModelState.Clear();` очистить привязки контроллера.